# Call Java code from a webpage from server

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am working on a web user interface using html, javascript and php. I wanted to create an upload button where I can upload an excel file and populate a graph using Apache Jena. The upload part is done, where the excel file is stored in a folder on the server side. I have also coded the population of a graph from an excel file using Java and Apache Jena importation. What I am unsure how to do is how can I call this java script from javascript? Do I need to install anything on the server?

Comment: A backend should normally expose an endpoint that you can call from the frontend (JavaScript) to trigger an action.

Comment: I would use a java REST service

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your java code into a java web application which will run in a servlet container (like Apache Tomcat). Then, you need to expose your code by writing a `HttpServlet`. Your servlet should get the name (or any other identifier) of the excel file as a request parameter which it would then pass to your graph generation code. Your code should then write the response (graph) back to the `OutputStream` of the `HttpServletResponse` object instead of the `OutputStream` of a file. This way when your HTML page will call the URL of your servlet, it will get back the graph in response.